# SongOrganzier Isnt Adding Song To txt File or Html Table

Tags: php, html

Problem:

Create a Song Organizer script that stores songs in a text file. Include functionality that allows users to view the song list and prevents the same song name from being entered twice. Also, include code that sorts the songs by name, deletes duplicate entries, and randomizes the song list with the shuffle() function.

How Come my code isnt adding the song to the txt file or the table?

My Solution - > Broken, song isnt being appending to song list

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 
Strict//EN"
"http://w...content-available-to-author-only...3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://w...content-available-to-author-only...3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>PHP Code Blocks</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type"
     content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Song Organizer</h1>
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
     if ((file_exists("SongOrganizer/songs.txt"))
          && (filesize("SongOrganizer/songs.txt")
          != 0)) {
          $SongArray = file(
               "SongOrganizer/songs.txt");
          switch ($_GET['action']) {

             case 'Remove Duplicates':
               $SongArray = array_unique($SongArray);
               $SongArray = array_values($SongArray);
             break;

             case 'Sort Ascending':
               sort($SongArray);
             break;
             case ’Shuffle’:
                shuffle($SongArray);
             break;



          } // End of the switch statement

          if (count($SongArray)>0) {
             $NewSongs = implode($SongArray);
             $SongStore = fopen("SongOrganizer/songs.txt","wb");
             if ($SongStore === false)
                  echo "There was an error updating the song ﬁle\n";
             else {
                  fwrite($SongStore, $NewSongs);
                  fclose($SongStore);
                  }
              }
          else
              unlink("SongOrganizer/songs.txt");     
              }

          }

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $SongToAdd = stripslashes(
          $_POST['SongName']) . "\n";
     $ExistingSongs = array();
     if (file_exists("SongOrganizer/songs.txt")
          && filesize("SongOrganizer/songs.txt")
          > 0) {
          $ExistingSongs = file(
               "SongOrganizer/songs.txt");
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $SongToAdd = stripslashes($_POST['SongName']) . "\n";
     $ExistingSongs = array();

     if (file_exists("SongOrganizer/songs.txt")
          && filesize("SongOrganizer/songs.txt")> 0) {
          $ExistingSongs = file("SongOrganizer/songs.txt");
         }

      }
   }
}



if ((!file_exists("SongOrganizer/songs.txt"))
     || (filesize("SongOrganizer/songs.txt")
     == 0))
     echo "<p>There are no songs in the
          list.</p>\n";
else {
     $SongArray = file(
          "SongOrganizer/songs.txt");
     echo "<table border=\"1\" width=\"100%\"
          style=\"background-color:lightgray\">\n";
     foreach ($SongArray as $Song) {
          echo "<tr>\n";
          echo "<td>" . htmlentities($Song) .
               "</td>";
          echo "</tr>\n";
     }
     echo "</table>\n";
}


?>
<p>
<a href="SongOrganizer.php?action=Sort%20Ascending">
     Sort Song List</a><br />
<a href="SongOrganizer.php?action=Remove%20Duplicates">
     Remove Duplicate Songs</a><br />
<a href="SongOrganizer.php?action=Shufﬂ e">
     Randomize Song list</a><br />
</p>
<form action="SongOrganizer.php" method="post">
<p>Add a New Song</p>
<p>Song Name: <input type="text" name="SongName"
     /></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit"
     value="Add Song to List" />
<input type="reset" name="reset"
     value="Reset Song Name" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the directory/file have write permission? Any errors in the log?

Comment: Put an echo in the else conditional of `if ($SongStore === false)`. Something like `echo "Attempting to write to file.";` and report back. Then we'll know if it's your logic or your permissions.

Comment: I have error checking here and its not printing so im assuming its working its just not adding anything to the table or file.         if ($SongStore === false)
                  echo "There was an error updating the song ﬁle\n"; So then i think its my permissions

Comment: You know what they say when you assume! It's quite possible there are no errors but the logic to get to that point is flawed so it never executes. Stick an echo on the line before fwrite to be absolutely sure it's making it there.

Comment: else {
                  echo "Is this working!"; does not seem to echo anything.

Comment: Alright, throw an echo right after the  `if (count($SongArray)>0) {` and see if it gets executed. `var_dump($SongArray);` make sure things are what you are expecting.

Comment: That doesn't echo anything unfortunately so the logic is flawed?

Comment: It would seem like there are some logic errors, try echoing something right before that if statement. If all else fails, throw in echos all over the place. `var_dump($_GET['action']);` at the start of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran your code locally. You're never sending an action in the form so none of the code is executing.

Inside the form, add something like:
`<input type="hidden" name="action" value="literally anything can go here" />`